Entrust to DigiCert SSL Certificate Migration
I got this email and I am not sure what I need to do about it. I am using the AuthorizeNet.dll and I believe this is using  https://api.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api or   https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api. So base on that I need to download a cert from this url https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api but I am not seeing anything related to the cert. Any help would be great.
https://support.authorize.net/knowledgebase/Knowledgearticle/?code=000003009
This link has attachment at the bottom of the page is that what I
need to install?

It came to our attention that the previous email had links that were not easily accessible. We apologize for any confusion. Here are
the correct links to the support articles with detailed instructions
below:
• Entrust to DigiCert SSL Certificate Migration (KA-05545)
• Latest Version of Authorize.net Server-Level SSL Certificates (000003009)
Who is being affected: Merchants who utilize Authorize.net APIs and endpoint URLs in their websites or applications will need to make
updates. They will need to integrate and use the newly-issued Root and
Intermediate (CA) SSL certificates from DigiCert. This should be done
before the scheduled revocation dates to avoid disruptions.
What you need to do: You must integrate and use the newly-issued Root and Intermediate (CA) SSL certificates from DigiCert by October
24 to avoid any disruptions. To help you fight fraud, AFDS is
automatically enabled on your account, which gives you access to many
powerful fraud filters, including:

https://support.authorize.net/_entity/annotation/c98db1ed-e281-ef11-ac21-6045bd065e37

Can you improve your question and add some more information for context? What are you trying to achieve? What service are you using? It sounds a bit like you are using some API and it's asking you to update the root certificate on your client side. How to do this depends on the lanuage and OS environment that you are running. Maybe you want to get familiar with the topic of SSL verification in your target language.

Authorize.net is terrible at communication. Not providing enough details, not providing specifics, having links and references that point nowhere, making mistakes in their emails... :( Why can't they say the name, version or of number the certificate so we can actually check if we have what we need? And why no way to test it than 1 day before...!

Any idea what we need to do for this

You are basically being asked to download the new certificates and import them into your certificate catalog because changes to their SSL/TLS secure communication will prevent communication between your Authorize.net APIs and their servers.
Use the built in .mmc certificate console to import the downloaded certificates into the systems that use or communicate with Authorize.net

Any idea where I would get it?

I was able to find the Root and CA DigiCert Certificates here at the end of this Authorize.net support article: https://support.authorize.net/knowledgebase/Knowledgearticle/?code=000003009
